# rich faces tree with unknown depth

Tags: richfaces

How can i create a directory structure with an unknown depth?

I want to show all files and folders as they are.I try to use rich:tree but i could not achive.This is a example code .But it shows only one parent folder and  files.

```
                 <rich:tree id="logs-tree" toggleOnClick="true"
                        switchType="client" value="#{externalSourceBrowser.root}"
                        nodeFace="#{log.type}" var="log">

                        <rich:treeNode type="directory" id="directory-log">
                            <f:facet name="icon">
                                <h:graphicImage value="/misc/iconFolder.gif" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{log.filename}" />
                        </rich:treeNode>

                        <rich:treeNode type="file" id="file-log">
                            <f:facet name="icon">
                                <h:graphicImage value="/misc/iconLeaf.gif" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <a4j:commandLink
                                value="#{log.filename}"
                                reRender="upload-panel-form">
                                <rich:componentControl for="upload-panel"
                                    operation="show" event="onclick" />
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{log}"
                                                             target="#{externalSourceBrowser.log}" />

                            </a4j:commandLink>
                        </rich:treeNode>

                    </rich:tree>
```

Comment: what did you try? How it failed?

Comment: Use case in exadel shows only pre known file structures i want to create a tree with rich:tree which has random structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive tree Adaptor for this purpose by the way rich faces has a lot dizayn problem i suggest every one to use primefaces it is  not mature but well dizayned.